# Ubercart alter product price when product added to cart

Tags: ubercart

I need to alter Ubercart product price on Ubercart 3, Drupal 7, when product is added to cart.
I need to check some conditions, and if met, change the price. I thought i can go with

```
function MYMODULE_uc_cart_item($op, &$item) {  
  switch ($op) {
    case 'load':
      drupal_set_message(t('It works!'), 'status');
      break;
  }
}
```

but not sure am i targeting right hook.

It seems that it does not work (it is not invoked).

Thanks for clues

Comment: `hooks` are the right way to programmatically interact with modules. May be you can set it with rules module, i am not sure.

Comment: no, i want to do it from my custom module. hook is described here, but cant get it to work: http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/hook_cart_item

Comment: Please post the code youre using in your custom module.

Comment: See updated code.

Comment: `function hook_uc_cart_item($op, &$item) { ` the work hook should be replaced with your modules name like `function YOURMODULENAME_uc_cart_item($op, &$item) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another hook you can play with [hook_uc_add_to_cart](http://api.ubercart.me/api/drupal/ubercart!uc_cart!uc_cart.api.php/function/hook_uc_add_to_cart/7)

```
Parameters:
$nid - the node ID of the product
$qty - the quantity being added
$data - the data array, including attributes and model number adjustments
```

Here is how to work with hooks

> Drupal's module system is based on the concept of "hooks". A hook is a
>   PHP function that is named foo_bar(), where "foo" is the name of the
>   module (whose filename is thus foo.module) and "bar" is the name of
>   the hook. Each hook has a defined set of parameters and a specified
>   result type.

`function hook_uc_cart_item($op, &$item) {` the work hook should be replaced with your modules name like

`function YOURMODULENAME_uc_cart_item($op, &$item)`

See [Hooks](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/group/hooks/7)

Comment: Sorry if question have misleaded you.I implemented it in my module, of course, by replacing hook with my module name (i have written some custom modules before). I cannot get it to work though, so I hope someone experienced in hooking Ubercart might help. sorry for trouble, i will try to change question  a bit.

Comment: @HoverFusion see my edit.

Comment: Nikhil, thanks for suggestion, here's my upvote :) and thanks for your effort. I answered the question myself, as it was issue with cache.

Comment: You suggested the hook that best fits my question, but my final goal is little more complex, so i will go mainly with uc_cart_alter, see my answer update.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in clearing cache. For some reason, clearing cache from Drush does not completely work. (I need to clear it from interface). It might be also APC i implemented at some point. I have issues when clearing cache for modules/other code.

**EDIT:**

I can't get hook_uc_cart_item to work so far. (even as [hook_cart_item](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/hook_cart_item))
[hook_add_to_cart](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/hook_add_to_cart) works, and
[hook_uc_cart_alter](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/hook_uc_cart_alter) also works (for me)

I think i might take **hook_cart_alter** approach, as it gets items every time cart is viewed, in fact, they say it gets loaded all the time, and they have warned of performance issue, but as i need to watch on cart all the time as i have some dynamic calculations depending what is in cart, i think, if devel and kcachegrind dont complain, i will not, too :)

I see **uc_coupon module** also uses hook_cart_alter without fear :)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I can't remember, it was ages ago! :) Sorry

Comment: Posting my answer because it took me 2 hours to find what seems so obvious now.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved it:

```
function mymodule_uc_cart_alter(&$items) 
{
    $items[45]->price = 29393;
}
```

In this example I'm just hardcoding the change to demonstrate how to change the value. Obviously you would apply your own logic here based on whatever your requirements are.