# In Ubercart Which Hook is reponsible for adding product to the cart page(On clicking add-cart-button)?

Tags: 7, ubercart

In ubercart,While buyer sees a product and clicks on add-to-cart button for buying that product, i want to know which action is responsible for that product being added in to the cart?

I want to edit the sell price, so that only this question.
Already tried this hook, but it was not printing anything,

```
    mymodulename_uc_add_to_cart($nid, $qty, $data) {
    print "<pre>";print_r($data);print "</pre>";exit;

    if ($qty > 1) {
        $result[] = array(
                'success' => FALSE,
                'message' => t('Sorry, you can only add one of those at a time.'),
        );
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Which of these hooks

**hook_uc_add_to_cart

hook_uc_add_to_cart_data

hook_uc_cart_checkout_start

hook_uc_cart_display

hook_uc_cart_item_delete

hook_uc_cart_item_insert

hook_uc_cart_item_presave

hook_uc_cart_item_update

hook_uc_cart_pane

hook_uc_cart_pane_alter

hook_uc_checkout_complete

hook_uc_checkout_pane

hook_uc_checkout_pane_alter

hook_uc_update_cart_item

uc_checkout_pane_callback**

is responsible for adding quantity and price to cart in the cart page.Or is there any other hook which is doing it ?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to alter the cart item, then you can use `hook_uc_cart_alter` of ubercart.

This hook is not in documentation of `ubercart 7` but its still working for `Ubercart 7`.

> This is called every time the cart is rebuild (e.g. when products are
>   added), so it's a good place to alter the cart item.

I have checked `uc_coupon` module and hook `hook_uc_cart_alter` is implemented into that module. So, you can try this hook.

Edit:
Code snippets to modify the price of item

```
/**
 * Implements uc_cart_alter.
 */
function mymodule_uc_cart_alter(&$items ) {

  foreach ($items as $index => $item) {

   //you can add condition for your bid product

    $items[$index]->price = 100;
  }
}
```

For reference:

http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/hook_uc_cart_alter

Comment: I am not using uc_coupon. Before product is added to cart page(if i click on add-to-cart button), i want to alter the sell price of tat product ? is tat possible using hook_uc_cart_alter? If so how?

Comment: @Ram, Yes, its possible to alter `sell price` of the product. I only mentioned `uc_coupon` module, so you know that this hook is working in other contrib module.

Comment: Let me try hook_uc_cart_alter

Comment: on clicking on add-to-cart button in hook_uc_cart_alter, it doesn't have currently added product in the order object. 
$order = new UcOrder();
 $order->products = $items;
 $order->data = array(); 
 print "<pre>";
 print_r($order);exit;
 print "</pre>";

Comment: @Ram, `hook_uc_cart_alter` will allow you to alter the item of cart content. `$order` will automatically fetch the updated cart item by `hook_uc_cart_alter`.

Comment: While clicking on add-to-cart button  i want to change the sell-price of the ubercart-auction to be highest-bid amount as sell price . how can it be done in the hook_uc_cart_alter()?

Comment: @Ram, I have modified my answer. I hope it will help you.

Comment: i am able to change the price by using this function. foreach ($items as $index => $item) {  
  if(isset($item->uc_auction))
  {
    $highest_bid = $item->uc_auction['high_bid_amt'];
    $item->price = $highest_bid;
  }   
 } with this i am able to alter the price.Thanks

Comment: @Ram, Its my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

with little googling I found this,might be what you are looking for

core add to functionality is handled by

`uc_cart_add_item($nid, $qty = 1, $data = NULL, $cid = NULL, $msg = TRUE, $check_redirect = TRUE, $rebuild = TRUE`)

reference

http://api.ubercart.me/api/drupal/ubercart!uc_cart!uc_cart.module/function/uc_cart_add_item/7

But if you are looking for a hook which allows you to penetrate your codes,

```
hook_uc_add_to_cart($nid, $qty, $data)
```

reference

http://api.ubercart.me/api/drupal/ubercart!uc_cart!uc_cart.api.php/function/hook_uc_add_to_cart/7

Also check the following links for more info about different API's

http://api.ubercart.me/api/drupal/ubercart!uc_cart!uc_cart.api.php/7

http://api.ubercart.me/api/drupal/functions/7

**Updates:**

Checkout already being discussed thread for custom alteration of prices [here.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/57608/ubercart-alter-product-price-when-product-added-to-cart)

Comment: Tried all those and i can't find which one is the 'ONE'.Also  tried hook_uc_add_to_cart and it didnt help.

Comment: can you make sure if there is any cache issue

Comment: Already tried clearing cache stil no success.

Comment: @ram just to make sure if you have missed replacing hook with your module name, I am suggesting as your sample code does not reflect so

Comment: That's an example.In the code i have my module name only.

Comment: @Ram check the Update section in my answer if that helps you.

Comment: Already saw those things.That wat i have put as a function above.No luck.